# JdbcMessagestore - Query | DB Performance Issue

Tags: spring-integration, jdbctemplate

In Our application we make use of the correlation strategy using the JDBCMessageStore and we see the following query is running in background and affects the DB performance.

SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID) from VWS_OWNER.INT_MESSAGE where REGION=:1

Since we have x Millions of record full table scan results causing the issue.

Please some one explain me why its running and how to avoid the DB performance issue

Comment: Please, share some test-case to play from our side (or at least some config). Which Spring Integration version do you use? Is that `SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID)` a result of `MessageGroupStoreReaper` scheduled task?

Comment: Hi Artem, We dont have MessageGroupStoreReaper configured. On digging litlle bit found the below from our logs

Comment: 2016-11-08 09:18:05,382 DEBUG Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:693 - - Executing prepared SQL query
2016-11-08 09:18:05,382 DEBUG Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:627 - - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(GROUP_KEY) from VWS_OWNER.INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where REGION=?]
2016-11-08 09:18:05,383 DEBUG Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:110 - - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2016-11-08 09:18:05,385 TRACE Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils:225 - -

Comment: We are using both spring boot and spring integration . The above issue happens in a war where we have spring boot(1.2.4.RELEASE).   The query in the first post and the above one in logs are constantly polling/getting monitored, Please give an insight what is happening and how to avoid these being invoked

Comment: More logs.....- Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-11-08 09:18:05,390 DEBUG Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:693 - - Executing prepared SQL query
2016-11-08 09:18:05,391 DEBUG Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:627 - - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID) from VWS_OWNER.INT_MESSAGE where REGION=?]
2016-11-08 09:18:05,391 DEBUG Agent Heartbeat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:110 - - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

Comment: Who is `Agent Heartbeat`? I don't know that beast :-)

Comment: That's what we are trying to figure out as well. We thought it was part of the Boot's enable-Integration implementation or something. If that is not the case then any idea what triggers the calls to JdbcMessageStore.getMessageCount metthod

Comment: No op. There is no such a functionality in the Spring Integration Auto-Configuration. If you can share some simple Spring Boot application on the matter, I can play with that locally and will figure out what's going on.

Comment: But, eh. That "simple application" should reproduce those `Agent Heartbeat` logs anyway.

Comment: Hi Artem,   Thank you for the inputs. On more analysis found that "Agent Heartbeat" comes from Introscope. We use it for our monitoring. We are trying to work out on the configuration changes for the same with intorscope team.  Since it happens only in environments where pbd files is deployed am not able to share the code as it doesnt happen in local. Please suggest us a way to turn off/suppress the execution of the queries using any spring boot properties. Tried setting this spring.jmx.enabled=false but dint help. Thank You again Artem!!!

Comment: Cool! Glad to see that something has appeared. I wonder if you can still use that tool but without Spring Integration table polling

Comment: Yup not sure why its picking up as we are not facing the issue in other war which uses spring integration only. The war where we see this issue uses Springboot+spring-integration .

Comment: There should not be a lot of magic. Maybe you have some 'QueueChannel` with `JdbcMessageStore` and poller with high rate? Need more logs

Comment: Hi Artem, I work with Raghav. The JDBCMessageStore has the method ( getMessageCount) that results in the query but it is likely triggered from LifecycleMessageSourceMetrics. The latter is JMX enabled and introscope may be invoking it as part of the platform monitoring. We are working on fixing the introscope but in the meantime is it possible to disable the registration of the LifecycleMessageSourceMetrics class so that it is not available for monitoring ? I am thinking that this gets registered as part of the Spring Boot enableIntegration annotation but not able to figure out exactly.